# Transform PDF to image place text on it

Tags: files, media

I am hoping to find a drupal module that can transform a PDF to image and merge that image with another one. 
Use case scenario is basically placing an endorsement stamp on an image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [PDF to ImageField](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_to_imagefield).

> The PDF To ImageField module provides automatic conversion of uploaded
>   PDF files to images. It can be used either to create a snapshot of the
>   front page to use as a preview thumbnail, or to generate a gallery of
>   images from each page in the document.
>
> The module is implemented as an additional widget for File Field where
>   PDFs are uploaded to. It places generated images into a Image Field on
>   the same content type.

That will get you half way there. As for the 2nd requirement of image merging, you'll likely have to implement your own solution via Drupal's [node API/hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7) to manipulate the converted PDF image with your stamp.

Comment: Thanks Shawn,
I did come across that module. I think for the second part I might be able to use Textimage module. I will give these a try and pay back the results. I also want to convert back to PDF after stamping the images. There might be a module to do that, but does anyone know a simpler solution?